# Implementar una clase en programa con formularios

Tags: c#, poo

Tengo un programa que entregue como proyecto final y mi profesor me lo reviso y me dijo que el proyecto estaba bien pero que necesitaba implementar una clase para el calculo del costo de los productos para aprobar la materia.
Mi programa realiza un registro de ventas de productos hechos por impresión 3D y las acciones que el botón realiza es calcular el costo de los productos en base al tiempo de impresión y el precio de los materiales.
Aquí les dejo el programa por si alguien puede ayudarme:

https://github.com/Rafiki08/FormularioVentas_IS

Aquí las acciones del botón:

````
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {   
                int material = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                int tiempo = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                double costo = 0;

                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "PLA" || comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ABS")
                {
                    double a = material * 0.6;
                    double b = tiempo * 0.1;
                    double c = a + b;
                    costo = c + (c * 0.40);
                    textBox5.Text = costo.ToString();
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "TPU")
                {
                    double a = material * 0.8;
                    double b = tiempo * 0.1;
                    double c = a + b;
                    costo = c + (c * 0.40);
                    textBox5.Text = costo.ToString();
                }
                else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "PETG")
                {
                    double a = material * 0.85;
                    double b = tiempo * 0.1;
                    double c = a + b;
                    costo = c + (c * 0.40);
                    textBox5.Text = costo.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Asegurese de llenar correctamente todos los campos requeridos para poder calcular el costo, error:" + exe);
            }
        }```
````

Comment: y de casualidad investigaste que es y como se crea una clase en C# antes de pedir que te lo hagan: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+crear+clases

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tendrias que hablar con tu profesor. Crear una clase es un concepto generico. Te dieron una respuesta que puede estar bien o mal, dependiendo lo que pida tu profesor.

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría lo siguiente para no complicarnos tanto, crearía una clase y pondría un método estático para luego utilizarlo en la llamada. También le estoy pasando la opción que varia según lo que se seleccione en comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()

```
public class Costos
{
    public static double CalcularCosto(double material, double tiempo, string opcionMaterial)
    {
         double coeficienteMaterial = 0;
         if (opcionMaterial == "PLA" || opcionMaterial == "ABS")
                {        
                    coeficienteMaterial = 0.6;
                }
                else if (opcionMaterial == "TPU")
                {
                    coeficienteMaterial = 0.8;
                }
                else if (opcionMaterial == "PETG")
                {
                    coeficienteMaterial = 0.85;
                }
         double preCosto = (material * coeficienteMaterial) + (tiempo * 0.1);
         return preCosto + precosto * 0.4;
    }
}
```

Luego para invocarlo de la siguiente manera:

````
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {   
                    int material = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                    int tiempo = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                                             
                    textBox5.Text=Costos.CalcularCosto(material,tiempo,comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToString();       
                }
                catch (Exception exe)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Asegurese de llenar correctamente todos los campos requeridos para poder calcular el costo, error:" + exe);
                }
            }```
````

Comment: Aunque creaste una clase, tu clase no hace nada, ya que no difiere en nada de una funcion. Tendriamos que esperar a que OP clarifique mas que necesita, e igual va a ser dificil porque la respuesta correcta la tiene su profesor...

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por el comentario, he mejorado mi respuesta. Si bien es cierto que la clase así como esta solamente tiene la función de calcular costos, creo que satisface la pregunta ya que elimina el código repetido y también abstrae y oculta la lógica del calculo en el evento click. También se podría renombrar la clase con algo mas genérico como "Utilidades" y poner otros cálculos o lógicas de negocio dentro.